# How to auto submit saved/repopulated checkboxes using javascript

Tags: javascript

Can anyone show me how to auto submit my saved/repopulated checkbox options on page reload?  The checkboxes repopulate correctly once redirected to a page and then back again but I am not sure how to auto submit the results.

form

```
<form id="form" method="post" action="">
<input type="checkbox" name="2kandunder" class="checkbox" id="1" <?=(isset($_POST['2kandunder'])?' checked':'')?>/> $2000 And Under<br>

<input type="checkbox" name="2kto4k" class="checkbox" id="2" <?=(isset($_POST['2kto4k'])?' checked':'')?>/> $2001 To $4000<br>
</script>    
<input type="checkbox" name="4kandup" class="checkbox" <?=(isset($_POST['4kandup'])?' checked':'')?>/> $4001 And Up<br></td>
```

javascript that auto submits when box is checked.  I tried to implement this code into the javascript below I am using to repopulate the checked checkboxes but couldn't get it to work.

```
<script type="text/javascript">  
$(function(){
 $('.checkbox').on('change',function(){
    $('#form').submit();
    });
});
```

javascript I am using to repopulate the checkboxes after a user clicks on favorite button and is taken to a php script and then redirected back to this page.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.cookie/1.4.0/jquery.cookie.min.js"></script>

<script>
  $(":checkbox").on("change", function(){
    var checkboxValues = {};
    $(":checkbox").each(function(){
      checkboxValues[this.id] = this.checked;
    });
    $.cookie('checkboxValues', checkboxValues, { expires: 7, path: '/' })
  });

  function repopulateCheckboxes(){
    var checkboxValues = $.cookie('checkboxValues');
    if(checkboxValues){
      Object.keys(checkboxValues).forEach(function(element) {
        var checked = checkboxValues[element];
        $("#" + element).prop('checked', checked);
      });
    }
  }

  $.cookie.json = true;
  repopulateCheckboxes();



</script>
```

php

```
if (isset($_POST["2kandunder"])) {
$arguments[] = "`2kandunder` = 'yes'";
}
if (isset($_POST["2kto4k"])) {
 $arguments[] = "`2kto4k` = 'yes'";
}
if (isset($_POST["4kandup"])) {
$arguments[] = "4kandup = 'yes'";
}
if(!empty($arguments)) {
$str = implode(' AND ',$arguments);

$qry = "SELECT favorite_id, id, venue, imageurl FROM venue_ads WHERE `showingads` = 'yes' AND " . $str . "";


$result = $conn->query($qry);



 if ($result->num_rows > 0)
```

The checkboxes repopulate correctly but doesn't submit anything.  How can I make the repopulate javascript submit the checkboxes that are repopulated?

Answer (score 0):

I'm probably misreading your question, because it seems like you could just follow your call to `repopulateCheckboxes()` with a form-submit, like so:

```
repopulateCheckboxes();
document.getElementById('form').submit();
```

Maybe you could toss up a jsbin example?

Comment: This is basically exactly what I am looking for and I thought for sure it would work, but It causes parts of the page to glitch and then goes to "this page cant be displayed" after about 5 seconds of page blinking?

Comment: Put your code up on jsfiddle or something similar and point me at it.

Comment: Please forgive my ignorance but I am very new to javascript and have never used jsfiddle.  I tried to use the jsfiddle but there are no results.  I have a php script on this same page that reads what is posted once a checkbox is clicked then creates a new query based on which boxes are checked.  There is no spot in jsfiddle for all these script types so not sure what to do?  Everything works fine I am just now trying to implement the save/repopulate function which works fine but it just doesn't post which boxes are checked to the php script..

Comment: That's okay. Point me at your server then, if it's public. I don't mind taking a look. It's just very unclear to me what you're trying to accomplish at the moment. Why would you want to auto-submit a form (using JavaScript) if its default values are populated by PHP? If they're already being passed to your PHP as _POST variables, why don't you just handle them on the initial request?

Comment: I guess the real question here would be, why isn't the checked box posting to my php script in order to filter the correct results.  All checkboxes and filters work perfect until they are directed away from the page and then come back.  Once they come back it saves the boxes that are checked properly but then it is displaying everything even with the box checked?  I have to uncheck the box then check it again to get the correct filter.

Comment: I'm not sure, seeing only half the picture, but it sounds like the root cause for this might be in your PHP code (which I can't see).

Comment: Here is the link.  http://www.mybudgetbride.com/ad-display-template.php.  Click on $2000 and under box and it will display just one ad.  Then click search (this will be a favorites button) which will send you to a php script to save favorite to my database and then will redirect you back to page listed.  The problem, as you will see is the $2000 and under box is checked like it should be but the filter results are not correct.

Comment: Use test for username and test for password

Comment: I see what you're describing. I'm guessing there's a race condition between whatever's reading session data and setting the cookie. But I can't see your PHP so I'm missing a large chunk of the code. (By the way, you're loading jQuery twice -https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js and http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js).

Comment: Ah, so I think the issue is that...when your page first loads, PHP is only looking in the _POST - but the data doesn't exist there yet, only in a cookie. JavaScript can read that cookie and so it can pre-populate the form. When a field changes, JavaScript auto-submits the form- which puts that data into the _POST where PHP can read it. So what you probably need to do is either (A) have your PHP fallback to the cookie if no _POSTS data exists or (B) auto-submit the form (the first time only) if cookie data is found so that PHP can share it.

Comment: thanks for all the help. If you don't mind could you show an example of how to have the php fall back to the cookie if post doesn't exist?

Comment: No problem. I haven't written PHP in about 10 years though, mate. You'll probably have as much as luck as I would Googling for that one. I think so long as your PHP and JavaScript are on the same domain, it should be possible. Good luck! :)