# How to save checkbox state and post values to page after user clicks next pagination page or on page refresh?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, checkbox

What is the best way to save the state of checked checkboxes and POST the value of those checkboxes after a page refresh?  In this situation I have multiple checkboxes to filter results from a MySQL database.  Once a box is checked it updates my query and the results will display.  The problem I am having is I am now adding pagination.  When a user clicks to go to the next page of results, the checkboxes that were selected unchecks, and the php isn't reading that anything was posted and the query runs without the values of the checkbox included in the query.

How can I save the checked checkboxes and POST those values to my query even after page reload or after a user clicks to go to the next set of pagination results?

Here is html form:

```
<form id="form" method="post" action="">

<input type="checkbox" name="2kandunder" id="2kandunder" onchange="$('#form').submit();" class="checkbox" id="2kandunder" <?=(isset($_POST['2kandunder'])?' checked':'')?>/>

<input type="checkbox" name="2kto4k" id="2kandunder" class="checkbox" onchange="$('#form').submit();" <?=(isset($_POST['2kto4k'])?' checked':'')?>/>   

<input type="checkbox" name="4kandup" id="4kandup" class="checkbox" onchange="$('#form').submit();" <?=(isset($_POST['4kandup'])?' checked':'')?>/> 

</form>
```

And the PHP to post checkbox values into a string and then into a query to filter results.

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST["2kandunder"])) {
$arguments[] = "AND `2kandunder` = 'yes'";
}
if (isset($_POST["2kto4k"])) {
$arguments[] = "AND `2kto4k` = 'yes'";
}
if (isset($_POST["4kandup"])) {
$arguments[] = "AND 4kandup = 'yes'";
}
if(!empty($arguments)) {
$str = implode($arguments);
}
?>
```

Is it possible to use sessions for this?

Comment: TRY THIS ONE:
    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3313595/saving-checkbox-state-on-reload

Comment: @makjal  I played around with that example but being so new to javascript or jquery I couldn't get it to work.  Also couldn't wrap my head around how using this method could POST the checked checkboxes each time the page is reloaded or when a user clicks to the next pagination page?

Comment: @MujahedAKAS  this was an old question I posted that never was really resolved. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28709000/how-to-auto-submit-saved-repopulated-checkboxes-using-javascript/28709212?noredirect=1#comment45736906_28709212 I used this javascript to keep the state of the checkbox checked on page reload but I couldn't figure out how to make this code post to my php script as well each time the page reloads?

Comment: @bg2982, is it working now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can do it via session, do this in your php script

```
if (isset($_POST["2kandunder"]))           
        {
           $_SESSION["kandunder"]=TRUE;
        }
```

and in your html page insert a php script after `submit();`

```
<?php
     if (isset($_SESSION["kandunder"]) && ($_SESSION["kandunder"]))
     {
       echo 'checked';
     }
 ?>
```

Don't forget to start the session on both pages, and destroy/unset session after work done. And apply same logic for remaining 2 checkboxes.

Comment: Thanks for the example. I somewhat got it to work and see the logic behind it.  2 problems now.  First, the checkbox doesn't stay checked after going to next pagination page.  Is that possible to do with this method?  Also, once a checkbox is clicked since it is stored in the session it will always be included in the query.  So for example if the user wanted to uncheck a box is there a way for them to kill just that session variable by unchecking the box?  First I would need the box to stay checked in the first place I guess before anything else?

Comment: Tell me one thing,Does user needs to clicks on submit button every time he/she checks/unchecks checkbox?

Comment: No there is no submit button

Comment: Then you need to do it via AJAX, through onchange() event.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  I just tagged you in a comment with a link to an old question I had posted.  I was able to get that script to save the checkbox state but I couldn't figure out how to make it post to the php script that creates the string to include to my query.  Maybe you could help with that?

Comment: I had same problem while developing shopping cart website, but when I tried to add to cart using ajax it updates real-time, but when I refreshed page all updated values lapse, So I ended up with AJAX and session same time, so after updating page with ajax if user refresh than it will be displayed via session. This is what I understood you want to achieve.

Comment: Hi @bg2982 if this or any answer has solved your question please consider accepting it http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/287197 by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.